# Firebird Database with Visual Studio 2008 not working

Tags: c#, database, dll, firebird

I am on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2008. I installed Firebird 3.0 (the latest version), and I wanted to connect to the database using C#. I also installed Firebird DDEX for Visual Studio 2008. However, when I tried to add `firebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll` to the reference in the project, it gave an yellow triangle with an exclamation mark inside.

Some old Stack Overflow solutions said I should install an older version of Firebird, so I uninstalled version 3.0, and replaced it with version 2.5.2. I now have `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll` added to the reference without the yellow triangle problem.

However, it looks like this is not the only issue. I wrote my program similar to [this example](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/):

```
string connectionString =
    "User=SYSDBA;" +
    "Password=masterkey;" +
    "Database=temp.fdb;" +
    "DataSource=localhost;" +
    "Port=3050;" +
    "Dialect=3;" +
    "Charset=NONE;" +
    "Role=;" +
    "Connection lifetime=15;" +
    "Pooling=true;" +
    "MinPoolSize=0;" +
    "MaxPoolSize=50;" +
    "Packet Size=8192;" +
    "ServerType=0";

FbConnection myConnection = new FbConnection(connectionString);

try{
    // Open connection
    MessageBox.Show("Open connection");
    myConnection.Open();

    // Close connection
    MessageBox.Show("Close connection");
    myConnection.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex){
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

}
```

I have my temp.fdb in my application directory. I have also created database and a table with some data in it using command prompt.
However, this gives an error:

> I/O error during "CreateFile(open)" operation for file "temp.fdb"
>   Error while trying to open file.

I changed it the ServerType from 0 to 1, and I got a new error:

> Unable to load DLL 'fbembed': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)".

When I try to add `fbembed.dll` to the reference, it gives the following error:

> A reference to '.....\bin\fbembed.dll' could not be added. Please make
>   sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or
>   COM component

When I did some research on this, I found I need to have all `icu*.dll`'s, intl folder, and udf folder in the application directory as well. So I moved all of those to the application directory, but I am still getting the same error.

Can someone give me some advice on how to fix this issue?

Comment: How is your Firebird server configured?

Comment: What was the error associated with the yellow triangle? Do you want to use Firebird embedded, or do you want to connect to a Firebird server? If the last, don't bother with getting Firebird embedded to work: it won't help with connecting to Firebird server. Note that the CreateFile error means you are trying to connect to a database that does not exist (or access is denied). What were the Stack Overflow answers that suggested to install an older Firebird version (because that really should not be related to installing Firebird ado.net)? Which version of Firebird ADO.net are you installing?

Comment: Also, why are you using Visual Studio 2008? What CLR version are you targeting? Are you using .NET 2.0 - 4.0-compatible client libraries?

Comment: And when downgrading from Firebird 3, why install 2.5.2, and not 2.5.7?

Comment: Try to use full path to db

Comment: Do not use Visual Studio 2008,technology moves very fast and no one should have to maintain anything for Visual Studio 2008, you can get community versions of Visual Studio for free so do not make it into a money issue

Comment: Omg Thank you everyone for quick comments. I thought I saw on old SO question that someone with the similar issue as mine got it work after he downgraded it to 2.5.2.

I guess I was trying everything I could do, and tried everything that I found online.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I don't really like VS 2008, but our company uses it :/

Comment: Btw, I just got it to work only with a change on a line of code. Like @rstrelba mentioned, I used the full path to the database, and it started working! I guess I did not have to go through all these messy stuff... Thank you everyone anyway for your help!

Comment: 1) " "Charset=NONE;" does not seem a brightest idea 2) try working with www.IBProvider.com

Comment: Hello, maybe you can help me. I use VS 2008 and when i add the Firebird.dll i get every time the yellow triangle. I used the Firebird dll version 2.6.5. i can't find the dll version 2.5.2 :/ maybe you can upload the dll or your project so i can try this :D